# How to calculate centroids of HAC clusters?

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I ran a HAC (Hierarchical Agglomerative Clustering) using the Iris dataset in R. However, I don't know how to calculate the centroids of `i1`, `i2`, `i3` for each cluster.

My goal is to make a "Buckshot" clustering algorithm.

This is my code:

```
irists <- read.csv("irists.csv", header = TRUE)
str(irists)
irists.m <- as.matrix(irists[,1:4])
dm <- dist(irists.m, method = "euclidean")
hc <- hclust(dm, method = "complete")
plot(hc)
clusterCut <- cutree(hc,3)
clusterCut
i1 <- iristr.m[c(1,4,12),] #HAC cluster's result
i1 
i2 <- iristr.m[c(2,5,8),] #HAC cluster's result
i2
i3 <- iristr.m[c(3,6,7,9,10,11),] #HAC cluster's result
i3
```

How do I calculate the centroids of `i1`,`i2`,`i3`?

Can I apply the same method for calculating the centroids to text data (e.g. `20newsgroup` of "reuters-21578")?

Comment: Perhaps using `colMeans`?

Comment: thank you for your help Roman Luštrik!!